# How to move files from one directory to another?

Tags: scripting, vbscript

I have a requirement and I'm not really sure how to go about it. I need to write an VBScript to look for certain files in a specified directory. If the file is found I then need to move it into a a different directory(Archive).

For example, I have file Z001_130711.txt in directory C:\Transfer, the first four characters of the filename will always be the same what would change is the last 6 characters which as you can see is the date of when the file was created/run.

Before I move the file I have to do some other things and for that I came up with the VBScript code already.

After I'm done I need to move it to C:\Transfer\Archive. This where I'm stuck and I don't know how to do it.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: If you want to use vbscript why did you tagged this question with VB.NET?

Comment: How do you identify the file if you don't know the exact name? Will there always be only one file with a name `Z001_*`? Also, you may want to check the [`FileSystemObject` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This should get you most of the way.  You'll need to figure out the correct replacement for the phrase "If UCase(Right(objFile.Name, 4)) = ".VBP" Then"

Also the destination files have ".bak" appended.  You'll need to remove that.

The rational for placing the list of files in a Dictionary escapes me at the moment.  I think it had to do with the process failing often enough that I needed to be able to get the list of files that were handled vs those that didn't.

```
Option Explicit

Dim dicFiles 
Set dicFiles = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Private Sub AddFile(objFile)
  If dicFiles Is Nothing Then
    Set dicFiles = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  End If
  If Not dicFiles.Exists(objFile.Path) Then
    dicFiles.Add objFile.Path, "False"
  End If
End Sub

  Dim strRootPath 'As String
  Dim objFSO 'As New FileSystemObject
  Dim objFile 'As File
  Dim i 'As Integer
  Dim iMax 'as integer

  strRootPath = "C:\Transfer"
  Dim objFolder' As Folder
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strRootPath)

  'MsgBox "" & objFolder.Files.Count & " files in folder " & objFolder.Path
  For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'MsgBox "Filespec: " & objFile.Name
    If UCase(Right(objFile.Name, 4)) = ".VBP" Then 
      'MsgBox "Adding file " & objFile.Name
      AddFile objFile
    End If
  Next

  Dim arrFiles '() As Variant
  arrFiles = dicFiles.Keys

  'MsgBox "UBound(arrfiles)=" & UBound(arrFiles)

  Dim fsIn 'As String
  Dim fsOut 'As String
  Dim strFilespec 'As String
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrFiles)
    Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(arrFiles(i))
    strFilespec = arrFiles(i)
    fsOut = strFilespec & ".bak"
    If objFSO.FileExists(fsOut) Then
      objFSO.DeleteFile fsOut, True  'True = Force
    End If

    fsIn = strFilespec
    objFSO.MoveFile fsIn, fsOut

  Next

  Set objFSO = Nothing
```